# Negative number finder in index and occuring

Tags: python, list, function, loops, range

Write a func/on first_neg that takes a (possibly empty) list of
numbers as input parameter, finds the first occurrence of a
nega/ve number, and returns the index (i.e. the posi/on in the
list) of that number. If the list contains no nega/ve numbers or it
is empty, the program should return None. Use while loop (and
not for loop) and your while loop should stop looping once the
first nega/ve number is found.

This is the question my teacher asked me any ideas this what i did:

```
def first_neg(list):
    count = 0
    for number in list:
        if number < 0:
            count += 1
            return count
```

Dosent seem to work properly i just joined 1st post hope can get some help

Comment: Not your issue, but a compact answer: `def first_neg(l): next(idx for idx,i in enumerate(l) if i < 0)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Not sure if It's me or your code, but that returns `None`. I think you are missing a `return`

Comment: @MooingRawr Whoops it should be `return next(...` of course!

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [1,2,3,-5]

def first_neg(list):
    count = 0
    for number in list:
        count += 1      #moved it outside of the if
        if number < 0:
            return count

print(first_neg(x))   #prints 4
```

You want to increment `count` not when you've found the answer but everytime the `forloops` loops. Note that this method returns `4` which is the fourth item in the list, not the index, Index of the list starts from 0 so to access it would be `3`. Take our list `x = [1,2,3,-5]`, `-5` is in the fourth slot of the list, but to access it we have to call `x[3]` since lists starts at 0 indexing.

If you want to return the index of the list where the first negative number is found try this:

```
x = [1,2,3,-5]

def first_neg(list):
    for count, number in enumerate(list):
        if number < 0:
            return count

print(first_neg(x)) # prints 3
```

This is because enumerate creates a "pairing" of the item in the list and it's the current count. Enumerate just counts from 0 everytime it gets an item out of the list.

Also as a side note ( I didn't change it in my answer since I wanted you to understand what's going on ). Don't name your variables keywords like list, tuple, int, str... Just a bad idea and habit, it works as you can see but it can cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Return the index immediately once you encounter the negative element. Increment the index otherwise:

```
    def first_neg(lst):
        count = 0
        while count < len(lst):
            if  lst[count] < 0:
                return count
            count = count + 1
        return None
```

*Note : Better if you use enumerate() rather than using extra count variable. The code you mentioned is not written in pythonic way.*

---

You may try this as well:

```
   def first_neg(lst):
        res = [i for i,x in enumerate(lst) if x<0]
        return None if res == [] else res[0]
```

The code above can be improved using generators as suggested by @Chris_Rands.

Comment: This is quite wasteful, generating the entire list of negative numbers rather than short-circuiting at the first one. Using a generator with `next` as in my comment on the question is better

Comment: Looks like the guy is beginner. So not sure if he knows about generator.

Comment: If the OP is a beginner then list comprehension is not suitable either, and the standard for loop does short-circuit of course

Comment: May be you are correct. Edited my answer and have put suggestion for his code at first place.